# yield pattern, state machine flow

Tags: c#, .net, linq, yield

I have the following file and I am using an iterator block to parse certain re-occuring nodes/parts within the file. I initially used regex to parse the entire file but when certain fields were not present in a node, it would not match. So I am trying to use the yield pattern. The file format is as follows perceeded with the code I am using. All I want from the file are the replicate nodes as an individual part so I can fetch fields within it using a key string and store in collection of objects.  I can start parsing where the first replicate occurs but unable to end it where the replicate node ends.

**File Format:**

```
X_HEADER
{
    DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_2     NA
    DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_3     NA
    DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_4     NA
    SYSTEM_SOFTWARE_VERSION     NA
}
Y_HEADER
{
    DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_2     NA
    DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_3     NA
    DATA_MANAGEMENT_FIELD_4     NA
    SYSTEM_SOFTWARE_VERSION     NA
}
COMPLETION
{
    NUMBER          877
    VERSION         4
    CALIBRATION_VERSION 1
    CONFIGURATION_ID    877    
}
REPLICATE
{
    REPLICATE_ID            1985
    ASSAY_NUMBER            656
    ASSAY_VERSION           4
    ASSAY_STATUS            Research
    DILUTION_ID         1
}
REPLICATE
{
    REPLICATE_ID            1985
    ASSAY_NUMBER            656
    ASSAY_VERSION           4
    ASSAY_STATUS            Research
}
```

**Code:**

```
static IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> ReadParts(string path)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        var current = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

            if (line.StartsWith("REPLICATE"))
            {
                yield return current;
                current = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }
            else
            {
                var parts = line.Split('\t');
            }

            if (current.Count > 0) yield return current;
        }
    }
}

public static void parseFile(string fileName)
    {
        foreach (var part in ReadParts(fileName))
        {
           //part["fIELD1"] will retireve certain values from the REPLICATE PART HERE
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aer you ignoring the X_HEADER, Y_HEADER, and COMPLETION portions of your input?

Comment: Yes, I want to ignore everything but the replicate nodes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `yield return current;` after your while loop is over, you will get the final dictionary.

I believe it would be better to check for '}' as an end to the current block, and then put the `yield return` there.  although you can't use regex t parse the entire file, you can use regex to search for the key-value pairs within the lines.  The following iterator code should work.  It will only return dictonaries for REPLICATE blocks.

```
 // Check for lines that are a key-value pair, separated by whitespace.
// Note that value is optional
static string partPattern = @"^(?<Key>\w*)(\s+(?<Value>\.*))?$";

static IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> ReadParts(string path)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Ignore lines that just contain whitespace
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue; 

            // This is a new replicate block, start a new dictionary
            if (line.Trim().CompareTo("REPLICATE") == 0)
            {
                yield return parseReplicateBlock(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static IDictionary<string, string> parseReplicateBlock(StreamReader reader)
{
    // Make sure we have an opening brace
    VerifyOpening(reader);
    string line;
    var currentDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Ignore lines that just contain whitespace
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

        line = line.Trim();

        // Since our regex used groupings (?<Key> and ?<Value>), 
        // we can do a match and check to see if our groupings 
        // found anything. If they did, extract the key and value. 
        Match m = Regex.Match(line, partPattern);
        if (m.Groups["Key"].Length > 0)
        {
            currentDictionary.Add(m.Groups["Key"].Value, m.Groups["Value"].Value);
        }
        else if (line.CompareTo("}") == 0)
        {
            return currentDictionary;
        }
    }
    // We exited the loop before we found a closing brace, throw an exception
    throw new ApplicationException("Missing closing brace");
}

private static void VerifyOpening(StreamReader reader)
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Ignore lines that just contain whitespace
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

        if (line.Trim().CompareTo("{") == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Missing opening brace");
        }
    }
    throw new ApplicationException("Missing opening brace");
}
```

**Update:** I made sure that the regex string includes cases where there is no value.  In addition, the group indexes were all changed to use the group name to avoid any issues if the regex string is modified.

Comment: If some of my values are empty but the key is present for instance  AssayNumer         the regex does not macth the key. I am trying to make it so that if there is a key then it should match and blank if the value is not there, im using this as the regex  static string partPattern = @"^(?<Key>\w+)\s+(?<Value>.+)$";  any thoughts on this?

Comment: Ok, it'll require two small updates, one is making the value optional, and the other is updating the logic that uses the key.  I'll update the solution to have both of these changes.

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct. i changed the regex to static string partPattern = @"^(?<Key>\w+)\s*(?<Value>.*)$"; so it allows date or null. it runs fine

Comment: I did a quick test and it should return cases where there is no value specified.  If you want to change the regex string, you should probably convert the lines where it is indexing the groups to use the string indexer, rather than the int one, like I did.  Otherwise, you'll get funny results if you change which groups match to which numerical indexes.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it sounds like you just need to "close" a section when you get a closing brace, and only `yield return` at that point. For example:

```
static IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> ReadParts(string path)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        string currentName = null;
        IDictionary<string, string> currentMap = null;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (line == "{")
            {
                if (currentName == null || currentMap != null)
                {
                    throw new BadDataException("Open brace at wrong place");
                }
                currentMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }
            else if (line == "}")
            {
                if (currentName == null || currentMap == null)
                {
                    throw new BadDataException("Closing brace at wrong place");
                }
                // Isolate the "REPLICATE-only" requirement to a single
                // line - if you ever need other bits, you can change this.
                if (currentName == "REPLICATE")
                {
                    yield return currentMap;
                }
                currentName = null;
                currentMap = null;
            }
            else if (!line.StartsWith("\t"))
            {
                if (currentName != null || currentMap != null)
                {
                    throw new BadDataException("Section name at wrong place");
                }
                currentName = line;
            }
            else
            {
                if (currentName == null || currentMap == null)
                {
                    throw new BadDataException("Name/value pair at wrong place");
                }
                var parts = line.Substring(1).Split('\t');
                if (parts.Length != 2)
                {
                    throw new BadDataException("Invalid name/value pair");
                }
                currentMap[parts[0]] = parts[1];
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Now that's a pretty ghastly function, to be honest. I suspect I'd put this in its own class instead (possibly a nested one) to store the state, and make each handler its own method. Heck, this is actually a situation where the state pattern could make sense :)

Comment: It seems like it's ok the way it is. Of course, I don't know to which class this method belongs and I agree to put this in a class specific for parsing it. But I think it's ok with that.

Comment: @ivowiblo: I don't think that's okay at all - *much* too long to be a sane method, to be honest. But good enough as an answer leading the way to refactoring ;)

Comment: Thanks for your input, im trying to test, the var currentMap cannot be set as null. Should it be a certain type?

Answer (score 2):

```
private IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> ParseFile(System.IO.TextReader reader)
{
    string token = reader.ReadLine();

    while (token != null)
    {
        bool isReplicate = token.StartsWith("REPLICATE");
        token = reader.ReadLine(); //consume this token to either skip it or parse it

        if (isReplicate)
        {     
            yield return ParseBlock(ref token, reader);
        }
    }
}

private IDictionary<string, string> ParseBlock(ref string token, System.IO.TextReader reader)
{
    if (token != "{")
    {
        throw new Exception("Missing opening brace.");
    }

    token = reader.ReadLine();

    var result = ParseValues(ref token, reader);

    if (token != "}")
    {
        throw new Exception("Missing closing brace.");
    }

    token = reader.ReadLine();

    return result;
}

private IDictionary<string, string> ParseValues(ref string token, System.IO.TextReader reader)
{
    IDictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    while (token != "}" and token != null)
    {
        var args = token.Split('\t');

        if (args.Length < 2)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        result.Add(args[0], args[1]);

        token = reader.ReadLine();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Well I tested this out, it does not move past the first line. hmm ill test again